# ADOX - How to add Query inside MS Access database?

Tags: c++, database, ado, c++builder, adox

I'm using C++ Builder and having trouble adding query inside MS Access (2003) database. I use this code:

```
CatalogPtr cat = CoCatalog::Create();
VARIANT myConnectionString;
myConnectionString.vt = VT_BSTR;
myConnectionString.bstrVal = ADOConnetion1->ConnectionString.c_bstr();
cat->set_ActiveConnection(myConnectionString);

VARIANT mySQL;
mySQL.vt = VT_BSTR;
mySQL.bstrVal = L"Select * from table1";
cat->Views->Append(L"TestQuery", mySQL.pdispVal);
```

Compiling is OK, but when running this code I get access violation... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to just run a query on a table in your Access database from your form?

Comment: No. I'm trying to save a query inside MS Access.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it has to do with the mySQL VARIANT.  It looks like you are supposed to pass in something a little different.  The only reference to ADOX I found was in VB but if this helps.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx